# Facebook SDK 4.x openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: allowLoginUI: completionHandler: ^ upgrade

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xcode6

I am upgrading the Facebook SDK in my app and I had a question about it.
How do I handle the FBSession openActiveSession method in the new Facebook SDK 4.x?
I am currently using the following:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:readPermissions handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            DDLogInfo(@"Facebook: error! %@", error);
            [self fbResync];
            [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:readPermissions handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
               //TODO: Handle error
            }];
        }else if (result.isCancelled){
            [self closeSession];
        }else{
            if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"public_profile"]) {
                if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                        if (!error) {
                            [self registerUserWithFacebook:(NSDictionary *) result];
                        }
                    }];
                }
            }
        }
    }];
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is not working with this code?